# How to solve 'org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException' exception

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Trying to join two Datasets in Scala spark, namely **input** and **metric**

They look like this->

**input**:

```
+---------+----------+-----------------------------+------------------------+------+-------------------------+--------------------+----------+-----------------------------+------------------------+-----------------+----------+---------+----------+--------------------+---------+--------------------+-------------------+-------------------+--------------------+-------+-------------+------------+-----+------------+-------+-----------+-------------------+--------------------+----------------+--------------------+----------+-------------------+-------+---------+--------------------+---------------------+-------------+------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-------------+--------------+------------------+---------+----------+-------------+------------------+---------------+----------+----------+-----------------+----------------------------+------------+----------------+---------------+----------------------+---------------+-----------+-----------+---------------+--------------+--------+-----------+----------+
|   seller|global_agg|global_agg_visible_impression|global_agg_keyword_click|sl_agg|sl_agg_visible_impression|sl_agg_keyword_click|sl_stg_agg|sl_stg_agg_visible_impression|sl_stg_agg_keyword_click|seller_seller_tag|adblock_id|ad_tag_id|browser_id|      canonical_hash|device_id|         domain_name|     domain_pattern|     global_pattern| google_url_category|hour_id|is_valid_suid|mobile_model|os_id|rc_num_calls|referer|screen_size|   seasonal_pattern|          seller_tag|seller_top_level|             slot_id|state_code|       url_pattern2|    ctr|slideshow|is_commercial_url_nb|is_commercial_url_lda|keyword_click|visible_impression|       rpm_url_part0|       rpm_url_part1|       rpm_url_part2|       rpm_url_part3|sub_bidder_id|da_device_name|   da_mobile_model|da_is_app|da_os_name|cm_os_version|cm_browser_version|da_browser_name|stats_date|learner_id|mobile_model_misc|rc_num_call_akamai_corrected|referer_misc|screen_size_misc|adblock_id_misc|seller_adblock_id_misc|seller_tag_misc|seller_misc|global_vl2r|global_vl2r_kwc|global_vl2r_vi| sl_vl2r|sl_vl2r_kwc|sl_vl2r_vi|
+---------+----------+-----------------------------+------------------------+------+-------------------------+--------------------+----------+-----------------------------+------------------------+-----------------+----------+---------+----------+--------------------+---------+--------------------+-------------------+-------------------+--------------------+-------+-------------+------------+-----+------------+-------+-----------+-------------------+--------------------+----------------+--------------------+----------+-------------------+-------+---------+--------------------+---------------------+-------------+------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-------------+--------------+------------------+---------+----------+-------------+------------------+---------------+----------+----------+-----------------+----------------------------+------------+----------------+---------------+----------------------+---------------+-----------+-----------+---------------+--------------+--------+-----------+----------+
|8CUS3H6GJ|      3199|                         3199|                      81|   139|                      139|                   5|       139|                          139|                       5|  8CUS3H6GJ__misc|1293334731|146589733|         5|3f1163154992c27f5...|        2|   countryliving.com|       .%2anews.%2a|       .%2anews.%2a|People & Society ...|     23|            0|        iPad|    6|          13|      1|   834x1112|       .%2anews.%2a|           gpt_lb_11|       8PRVCXX19|2dbb87b0ca5118f9c...|        ma|       .%2anews.%2a|4.9e-04|        1|                  NA|                   NA|            0|                 1|countryliving.com...|countryliving.com...|countryliving.com...|countryliving.com...|          176|        TABLET|              IPAD|    false|       IOS|         14_8|      98.0.4758.97|  CHROME MOBILE|2022030813|        -1|             iPad|                         100|           1|            misc|           misc|       8CUS3H6GJ__misc|           misc|  8CUS3H6GJ|    0.02532|             81|          3199|0.031515|          5|       139|
|8CU8ND892|      3199|                         3199|                      81|     2|                        2|                   0|         2|                            2|                       0|  8CU8ND892__misc|1303809593|816510261|         6|0fadd20698c8eb489...|        4|         menupix.com|        .%2amen.%2a|        .%2amen.%2a|Food & Drink > Be...|     23|            0|       Other|    6|           7|      1|         NA|        .%2amen.%2a|       300-AFR1-Menu|       8PRVCXX19|5e1617c92cc745abe...|        mi|        .%2amen.%2a|4.0e-04|        0|           sensitive|                   NA|            0|                 1|menupix.com_menud...|menupix.com_menu.php|      menupix.com_NA|      menupix.com_NA|          186|       DESKTOP|     SAFARI - OS X|    false|      OS X|      10_15_6|              15.3|         SAFARI|2022030813|        -1|            Other|                           7|           1|              NA|           misc|       8CU8ND892__misc|           misc|  8CU8ND892|    0.02532|             81|          3199|0.024824|          0|         2|
|8CUS3H6GJ|      3199|                         3199|                      81|   139|                      139|                   5|       139|                          139|                       5|  8CUS3H6GJ__misc| 133963366|647881048|        16|02117a01ef3c83505...|        3|        iseecars.com|       .%2asale.%2a|       .%2asale.%2a|Autos & Vehicles ...|     23|            0|      iPhone|    6|           9|      1|    428x926|       .%2asale.%2a|jam_srp-m-breaker-18|       8PRVCXX19|           647881048|        fl|       .%2asale.%2a|5.1e-04|        0|           sensitive|                   NA|            0|                 2|iseecars.com_cars...|     iseecars.com_NA|     iseecars.com_NA|     iseecars.com_NA|          186|  MOBILE PHONE|GENERIC_SMARTPHONE|     true|       IOS|       15_3_1|                NA|         SAFARI|2022030813|        -1|           iPhone|                           9|           1|         428x926|           misc|       8CUS3H6GJ__misc|           misc|  8CUS3H6GJ|    0.02532|             81|          3199|0.031515|          5|       139|
|8CU5217S8|      3199|                         3199|                      81|   224|                      224|                  11|       224|                          224|                      11|  8CU5217S8__misc|1470166420|617251957|         6|97ad08b531a77a31a...|        3|      usmagazine.com|   .%2amagazine.%2a|   .%2amagazine.%2a|            Shopping|     23|            0|      iPhone|    6|           1|      1|    375x667|   .%2amagazine.%2a|                  NA|       8PRVCXX19|1632372f3fe8495e0...|        az|   .%2amagazine.%2a|3.5e-04|        0|                  NA|                   NA|            0|                 1|usmagazine.com_ho...|usmagazine.com_gl...|   usmagazine.com_NA|   usmagazine.com_NA|          128|  MOBILE PHONE|            IPHONE|    false|       IOS|         15_1|              15.1|         SAFARI|2022030813|        -1|           iPhone|                           1|           1|         375x667|           misc|       8CU5217S8__misc|           misc|  8CU5217S8|    0.02532|             81|          3199|0.041765|         11|       224|
|8CU4V40B1|      3199|                         3199|                      81|   456|                      456|                   7|       456|                          456|                       7|  8CU4V40B1__misc|1614514466|454554330|         6|dbeed4c1cd0dc94bd...|        3|makingthymeforhea...|   .%2amushroom.%2a|   .%2amushroom.%2a|        Food & Drink|     23|            0|      iPhone|    6|          11|      1|    375x812|   .%2amushroom.%2a|AdThrive_Content_...|       8PRVCXX19|77eca1e2d050c2dc0...|        ga|   .%2amushroom.%2a|0.0e+00|        0|                  NA|                   NA|            0|                 1|makingthymeforhea...|makingthymeforhea...|makingthymeforhea...|makingthymeforhea...|          133|  MOBILE PHONE|            IPHONE|    false|       IOS|       14_8_1|            14.1.2|         SAFARI|2022030813|        -1|           iPhone|                         100|           1|         375x812|           misc|       8CU4V40B1__misc|           misc|  8CU4V40B1|    0.02532|             81|          3199|0.017144|          7|       456|
|8CU4V40B1|      3199|                         3199|                      81|   456|                      456|                   7|       456|                          456|                       7|  8CU4V40B1__misc|1645741457|867854626|         6|9a19532f0607f1a67...|        3|  fitfoodiefinds.com|    .%2achicken.%2a|    .%2achicken.%2a|Food & Drink > Co...|     23|            0|      iPhone|    6|          19|      1|    414x896|    .%2achicken.%2a|AdThrive_Content_...|       8PRVCXX19|6c2626c75d0d61cea...|        fl|    .%2achicken.%2a|1.1e-04|        0|                  NA|                   NA|            0|                 1|fitfoodiefinds.co...|fitfoodiefinds.co...|fitfoodiefinds.co...|fitfoodiefinds.co...|          196|  MOBILE PHONE|            IPHONE|    false|       IOS|       14_7_1|            14.1.2|         SAFARI|2022030813|        -1|           iPhone|                         100|           1|         414x896|           misc|       8CU4V40B1__misc|           misc|  8CU4V40B1|    0.02532|             81|          3199|0.017144|          7|       456|
|8CU65T3AT|      3199|                         3199|                      81|     9|                        9|                   0|         9|                            9|                       0|  8CU65T3AT__misc|1708947332|642241257|         6|e850b035360db101e...|        3|        livestly.com|  .%2ahousehold.%2a|  .%2ahousehold.%2a|Home & Garden > H...|     23|            0|      iPhone|    6|           1|      1|    414x736|  .%2ahousehold.%2a|div-gpt-ad-149261...|       8PRVCXX19|3d94a0c408b09fc82...|        la|  .%2ahousehold.%2a|6.1e-04|        1|                  NA|                   NA|            0|                 2|livestly.com_hous...|     livestly.com_NA|     livestly.com_NA|     livestly.com_NA|          186|  MOBILE PHONE|            IPHONE|    false|       IOS|       14_7_1|            14.1.2|         SAFARI|2022030813|        -1|           iPhone|                           1|           1|            misc|           misc|       8CU65T3AT__misc|           misc|  8CU65T3AT|    0.02532|             81|          3199|0.023229|          0|         9|
|8CUS3H6GJ|      3199|                         3199|                      81|   139|                      139|                   5|       139|                          139|                       5|  8CUS3H6GJ__misc|1763942358|647881048|        22|f12d9cd1c53bb4d29...|        3|    caranddriver.com|.%2abest.%2asuv.%2a|.%2abest.%2asuv.%2a|Autos & Vehicles ...|     23|            0|      iPhone|    6|           1|      1|    375x812|.%2abest.%2asuv.%2a|           gpt_gal_a|       8PRVCXX19|           647881048|        ma|.%2abest.%2asuv.%2a|9.4e-05|        0|           sensitive|                   NA|            0|                 1|caranddriver.com_...|caranddriver.com_...|caranddriver.com_...| caranddriver.com_NA|          186|  MOBILE PHONE|            IPHONE|     true|       IOS|       15_2_1|                NA|         SAFARI|2022030813|        -1|           iPhone|                           1|           1|         375x812|           misc|       8CUS3H6GJ__misc|           misc|  8CUS3H6GJ|    0.02532|             81|          3199|0.031515|          5|       139|
|8CUXP6AUQ|      3199|                         3199|                      81|    19|                       19|                   0|        19|                           19|                       0|  8CUXP6AUQ__misc|1876213389|492267288|         6|2b2b8ce4d414d87c7...|        3|    wunderground.com|   .%2aforecast.%2a|   .%2aforecast.%2a|      News > Weather|     23|            0|       Other|    6|           2|      1|         NA|   .%2aforecast.%2a|   WX_Top300Variable|       8PRVCXX19|7d02cb34f1c34d1bf...|        co|   .%2aforecast.%2a|4.0e-03|        0|                  NA|                   NA|            0|                 1|wunderground.com_...| wunderground.com_us| wunderground.com_co|wunderground.com_...|          128|       DESKTOP|     SAFARI - OS X|    false|      OS X|      10_15_6|              15.3|         SAFARI|2022030813|        -1|            Other|                           2|           1|              NA|           misc|       8CUXP6AUQ__misc|           misc|  8CUXP6AUQ|    0.02532|             81|          3199|0.021277|          0|        19|
|8CUK5QD75|      3199|                         3199|                      81|   224|                      224|                  12|       224|                          224|                      12|  8CUK5QD75__misc|2026381580|373321055|        16|fbf8a2526836d2df7...|        3|thebestblogrecipe...|     .%2arecipe.%2a|     .%2arecipe.%2a|Food & Drink > Co...|     23|            1|      iPhone|    6|           1|      1|    414x896|     .%2arecipe.%2a|      content_mobile|       8PRVCXX19|4ff74ea6b06d13aea...|        mn|     .%2arecipe.%2a|2.1e-03|        0|                  NA|                   NA|            1|                 1|thebestblogrecipe...|thebestblogrecipe...|thebestblogrecipe...|thebestblogrecipe...|          196|  MOBILE PHONE| IPHONE 11 PRO MAX|     true|       IOS|       15_2_1|                NA|         SAFARI|2022030813|        -1|           iPhone|                           1|           1|         414x896|           misc|       8CUK5QD75__misc|           misc|  8CUK5QD75|    0.02532|             81|          3199|0.044852|         12|       224|
+---------+----------+-----------------------------+------------------------+------+-------------------------+--------------------+----------+-----------------------------+------------------------+-----------------+----------+---------+----------+--------------------+---------+--------------------+-------------------+-------------------+--------------------+-------+-------------+------------+-----+------------+-------+-----------+-------------------+--------------------+----------------+--------------------+----------+-------------------+-------+---------+--------------------+---------------------+-------------+------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-------------+--------------+------------------+---------+----------+-------------+------------------+---------------+----------+----------+-----------------+----------------------------+------------+----------------+---------------+----------------------+---------------+-----------+-----------+---------------+--------------+--------+-----------+----------+
only showing top 10 rows
```

**metric**

```
+---------+-----------------+------------------+-------------+--------+
|   seller|seller_seller_tag|visible_impression|keyword_click|    vl2r|
+---------+-----------------+------------------+-------------+--------+
|8CU5217S8|  8CU5217S8__misc|               224|           11|0.046841|
|8CUK5QD75|  8CUK5QD75__misc|               224|           12| 0.05088|
|8CUQJV5RI|  8CUQJV5RI__misc|                10|            1|0.038281|
|8CU29N1R8|  8CU29N1R8__misc|                 6|            0|0.022535|
|8CUS47X5W|  8CUS47X5W__misc|                 5|            1| 0.04156|
|8CU81SHO3|  8CU81SHO3__misc|                 2|            0|0.024337|
|8CUWMI118|  8CUWMI118__misc|                 1|            0|0.024821|
|8CU1NA8RS|  8CU1NA8RS__misc|                 1|            0|0.024821|
|8CU6I65Y2|  8CU6I65Y2__misc|                10|            0|0.020925|
|8CUWMQE3H|  8CUWMQE3H__misc|                66|            1|0.018842|
|8CUJKX6Y3|  8CUJKX6Y3__misc|                 4|            0| 0.02341|
|8CUYT9A1U|  8CUYT9A1U__misc|                 1|            0|0.024821|
|8CU27488H|  8CU27488H__misc|                 1|            0|0.024821|
|8CU7O5VP2|  8CU7O5VP2__misc|                 4|            0| 0.02341|
|8CUS3H6GJ|  8CUS3H6GJ__misc|               139|            5|0.034107|
|8CUJN5H60|  8CUJN5H60__misc|                72|            0|0.008559|
|8CUHN3BGE|  8CUHN3BGE__misc|                63|            4|0.049125|
|8CUQ5LJ63|  8CUQ5LJ63__misc|                13|            0|0.019829|
|8CUM545EY|  8CUM545EY__misc|                23|            0|0.016736|
|8CU94FM32|  8CU94FM32__misc|                32|            0|0.014532|
+---------+-----------------+------------------+-------------+--------+
```

What I am trying to execute->

```
input.as("input").join(broadcast(metric.as("metric"), Seq("seller","seller_seller_tag"), "left_outer")
```

This join operation breaks with the error:

```
Resolved attribute(s) seller_seller_tag#17561 missing from domain_pattern#10807,canonical_hash#10804,seller#10818,visible_impression#10829L,browser_id#10803,da_os_name#10838,domain_name#10806,slideshow#10825,os_id#10813,seasonal_pattern#10817,rpm_url_part1#10831,adblock_id#10801,da_browser_name#10841,da_mobile_model#10836,rpm_url_part3#10833,da_is_app#10837,seller_tag_misc#3625,referer#10815,seller_tag#10819,keyword_click#10828L,learner_id#10843,rpm_url_part2#10832,adblock_id_misc#2850,cm_os_version#10839,seller_misc#4023,global_pattern#10808,rc_num_calls#10814,screen_size#10816,google_url_category#10809,is_commercial_url_lda#10827,is_valid_suid#10811,url_pattern2#10823,stats_date#10842,sub_bidder_id#10834,da_device_name#10835,ad_tag_id#10802,hour_id#10810,seller_top_level#10820,mobile_model#10812,slot_id#10821,state_code#10822,device_id#10805,seller_adblock_id_misc#2899,screen_size_misc#2351,cm_browser_version#10840,rc_num_call_akamai_corrected#1385,is_commercial_url_nb#10826,ctr#10824,seller_seller_tag#3676,mobile_model_misc#1340,rpm_url_part0#10830,referer_misc#1866 in operator !Project [adblock_id#10801, ad_tag_id#10802, browser_id#10803, canonical_hash#10804, device_id#10805, domain_name#10806, domain_pattern#10807, global_pattern#10808, google_url_category#10809, hour_id#10810, is_valid_suid#10811, mobile_model#10812, os_id#10813, rc_num_calls#10814, referer#10815, screen_size#10816, seasonal_pattern#10817, seller#10818, seller_tag#10819, seller_top_level#10820, slot_id#10821, state_code#10822, url_pattern2#10823, ctr#10824, ... 28 more fields]. Attribute(s) with the same name appear in the operation: seller_seller_tag. Please check if the right attribute(s) are used.
```

Obviously, both "seller" and "seller_seller_tag" columns are present in the left and right datasets. The error message is ambiguous and I've been scratching my head over this since a couple of days now. Have tried several things including selecting only a few columns, joining only on the column "seller". All in vain

Answer (score 1):

I'm unable to reproduce your error, did you share all the transformations you've implemented to the dataframe after the join?

Try to rename the offending column, and subsequently join on the new field name:

```
  val metricRenamed = metric.withColumnRenamed("seller_seller_tag", "metric_seller_seller_tag")

  input.join(broadcast(metricRenamed), input("seller") === metricRenamed("seller") && input("seller_seller_tag") === metricRenamed("metric_seller_seller_tag"), "left_outer")
```

Comment: He is right. You have two `seller_seller_tag` cols #17561 and #3676 in the error mentioned. You need to either rename or get rid of one.